# detect point on a curve boundary

Tags: python, opencv, curve, smoothing

I have boundaries of semi-circle or ellipse shaped objects. Example image is [image]     [image]

The boundary can be slightly jagged (when you zoom in). I am looking to detect a point of interest (location x and y) on these curves, where we see a definite change in the shape, such as

[image][image]

There can be two outputs:

1. No point of interest: we cannot find specific features
2. Point of interest with x and y location

Currently, I am using Python and OpenCV. I cannot think of a efficient and effective way to solve this problem. Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, or tutorial service.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing says that others will agree with my closure vote, so ...

I suggest two steps:

1. Fit an ellipse to the given points.  I'm sure you've already found curve-fitting algorithms (and perhaps software packages) by now -- and asking for those is specifically proscribed on Stack Overflow.
2. Code a small anomaly detector, which works on the difference between the fitted curve and the actual data points.

Step 2 depends heavily on your definition of "point of interest".  What are the criteria?  I notice that your second point of interest actually lies very close to the fitted curve; it's the region on either side the deviates inward.

I suggest that you do your fitting in polar coordinates, and then consider the result in terms of theta and radius.  Think of "flattening" the two curves as a single unit, so that the central angle (theta) is the new x-coordinate, and the distance from the center is the new y-coordinate.

Now, subtract the two curves and plot the difference (or just store this new curve as an array of points).  Look for appropriate anomalies in these differences.  This is where you have to decide what you need.  Perhaps a sufficient deviation in the "r" value (radius, distance from center"); perhaps a change in the gradient (find a peak/valley, but not a gently sloping bulge).  Do you want absolute difference, or an integral of deviation (area between the fit and the anomaly).  Do you want it linear or squared ... or some other function?  Does the width of the anomaly figure into your criteria?

That's what you need to decide.  Does this get you moving?